# filtering data and load it to respective tables using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am fetching data from a store procedure that has a column transaction type and it has some values like (Direct, IMPS, net banking) now I wanted to filter the data according to these values and load it into different tables. anyone have any idea how we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Data Flow permits you to Branch and Filter your Source and write it to multiple Sink locations. Here is an image of a real world Data Flow that does exactly this:
[image]

Here are the steps:

1. Create the Source using your Stored Procedure
2. Branch the Source, once for each transaction type (this image represents 3 branches/types)
3. Apply a Filter to each Branch based on the transaction type criteria
4. Apply transforms based on the specific transaction types (optional)
5. Send the Transaction Type data to the appropriate Sink table(s).

Comment: Hello Joel but I don't want to use data flows is there any other way to do this

Comment: Then you'll have to write code to do it. Why not just use a visual graph in data flows to do it?

Comment: Actually the reason we are not using data flows is pricing.

Comment: If the Source and the Sink are on the same SQL server, you should consider using a Stored Procedure anyways. It will be the fastest and least expensive option.